# Yii2: yii\web\UrlManager does'nt make user-friendly urls

Tags: php, yii2

Here's urlManager configs:

```
return [
    'class'               => \yii\web\UrlManager::class,
    'enablePrettyUrl'     => true,
    'showScriptName'      => false,
    'baseUrl'             => '',
    'rules'               => [
        'page/<id:[\\w-_]+>' => 'page/index',
    ],
];
```

Here's urlManager using:

```
$menuItems = [
    [
        'label' => 'Home',
        'url' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['/page']),
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'About',
        'url' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['/page', 'id' => 'about']),
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Contact',
        'url' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['/page', 'id' => 'contact']),
    ],
];
```

And here's results from browser:

`http://localhost/page?id=about`

`http://localhost/page?id=contact`

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use exact route when creating URLs:

```
$menuItems = [
    [
        'label' => 'Home',
        'url' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['/page']),
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'About',
        'url' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['/page/index', 'id' => 'about']),
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Contact',
        'url' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['/page/index', 'id' => 'contact']),
    ],
];
```